# Model error: No nic with this ID () is registered

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am new to OMNeT++. I'm using OMNeT++ 5.2.1 and SuMO 0.30, and I'm trying to parked vehicles in specific parking zone using TraCI.
When the first car go parked in the parking zone at =114s, i get the following error

Model error: No nic with this ID (27) is registered with this ConnectionManager. -- in module (Veins::TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd) scenario.manager (id=6), at t=114s, event #6157

Why does this error happen?
Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: Which Veins version are you using?

Comment: I am using veins 4.7.1